# Automapper Aftermap "method not found" exception

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to use the `AfterMap` method to flatten the input class to output. The input classes look as following:

```
public class FooDTO {
  public string SomeFieldA { get; set; }
  public string SomeFieldB { get; set; }
  ....
  public BarDTO SomeFieldY { get; set; }
  public BazDTO SomeFieldZ { get; set; }
}

public class BarDTO {
  public string SomeOtherFieldA { get; set; }
}

public class BazDTO {
  public string YetAnotherFieldA { get; set; }
}
```

and the output class as following:

```
public class Foo {
  public string SomeFieldA { get; set; }
  public string SomeFieldB { get; set; }
  ....      
  public string SomeOtherFieldA { get; set; }
  public string YetAnotherFieldA { get; set; }
}
```

My AutoMapper mapping configuration looks as following:

```
CreateMap<FooDTO, Foo>()
   .AfterMap((src, dest, ctx) => ctx.Mapper.Map(src.SomeFieldY, dest))
   .AfterMap((src, dest, ctx) => ctx.Mapper.Map(src.SomeFieldZ, dest));
CreateMap<BarDTO, Foo>();
CreateMap<BazDTO, Foo>();
```

My problem is that when I try to run my application, I get the following unhandled exception:

```
 System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'AutoMapper.IMappingExpression`2<!0,!1> AutoMapper.IMappingExpression`2.AfterMap(System.Action`3<!0,!1,AutoMapper.ResolutionContext>)'.
```

Am I missing some other configuration? How do I make my code work?

Comment: Somehow you have mismatching AM versions. You must make sure there is only one version across the whole app.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, do you mean the Nuget package version?

Answer (score 5):

As Lucian Bargaoanu mentioned, it was caused by mismatch of versions of Nuget packages. Once I upgraded another project to version 9.0.0, it started to work.

Comment: In my situation I had to set the versions of 2 AutoMapper packages to 2 different versions, kind of not very consistent with their versioning of their packages.